# Adding laterals at connection using Water Utility Network Editing tool add in to ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.3, add-in

I am trying to use the Water Utility Network Editing tool add in using ArcMap 10.3.1 for the use of the **add laterals at connection** tool.

I am unfamiliar with adjusting config files but I have located the file and had a go at customizing it with my layer names.  So far I have been unsuccessful.

*The point layer **min_height_building_centre_2** I want to connect to the line layer **Wastewater_pipe_09_01_2017***

Here is a snapshot of the config file that I have adjusted.

[image: Snapshot of code]

```
 <!-- Begin Configuration for the Connect Closest Tools, this is an XML array of ConnectClosestDetails, you can specify any number of combinations -->
  <ConnectClosest>
    <!--start of entry-->
    <ConnectClosestDetails>
      <!--Point layer evaluated to connect to another-->
      <Point_Layer>min_height_building_centre_2</Point_Layer>
      <!--Line layer to connect the closest point to-->
      <Line_Layer>Wastewater_pipe_09_01_2017</Line_Layer>
      <!--The default editing template used to set the
      attributes of the new main-->
      <Line_EditTemplate>Wastewater_pipe_09_01_2017</Line_EditTemplate>
      <!--the distance to search for the closest feature-->
      <Search_Threshold>450</Search_Threshold>
      <Reset_Flow>Digitized</Reset_Flow>
    </ConnectClosestDetails>
    <ConnectClosestDetails>
      <Point_Layer>min_height_building_centre_2</Point_Layer>
      <Line_Layer>Wastewater_pipe_09_01_2017</Line_Layer>
      <Line_EditTemplate>Wastewater_pipe_09_01_2017</Line_EditTemplate>
      <Search_Threshold>450</Search_Threshold>
      <Reset_Flow>Digitized</Reset_Flow>
    </ConnectClosestDetails>
  </ConnectClosest>
  <!-- End Configuration for the Connect Closest Tools, this is an XML array of ConnectClosestDetails, you can specify any number of combinations -->
```

When I select the point features I am hoping to connect to the lines and press the *Add Laterals at Connections* tool, no lines are connected.

What steps have I missed or is there something further in the config file that I need to change?

[image: screenshot of map showing points not connected to lines]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking at the wrong section within the config for the add laterals at connection.

Instead of looking and configuring the **ConnectClosestDetails** section I should have configured the **AddLateralsLayers**.

After following the same procedure I had above to customize the file with my layer names within this section the tool was successful.

Comment: PLease mark this as resolved